# In C++ How can I tell the difference between integers and characters?

Tags: c++, character, integer

I am currently learning C++ and I have been asked to make a program which will calculate the interest that would be paid on a deposit of a given size. One of the requirements is that we display an error message when non-integer data is entered.

I however cannot work out how to detect if non-integer data has been entered. If anyone could provide an example of how this problem is solved it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't have to check yourself. The expression `(std::cin >> YourInteger)` evaluates to a bool, whcih is true if and only if `YourInteger` was succesfully read. This leads to the idiom

```
int YourInteger;
if (std::cin >> YourInteger) {
  std::cout << YourInteger << std::endl;
} else {
  std::cout << "Not an integer\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out if the input value contains non numeric characters. That is, anything other than 0-9.

You have to first take input as string and then verify if every digit is indeed numeric.

You can iterate the string and test if each character is a valid digit using the built in function isdigit() defined in `<cctype>`. You might also want to allow for a single comma if you're working with decimal numbers.

Answer (score 0):

[this](http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread258531.html) should be a clear enough starting point.

```
char* GetInt(char* str, int& n)
{
    n = 0;
    // skip over all non-digit characters
    while(*str && !isdigit(*str) )
        ++str;
    // convert all digits to an integer
    while( *str && isdigit(*str) )
    {
        n = (n * 10) + *str - '0';
        ++str;
    }
    return str;
}
```